# Why does removing border thickness and color keeping border width remove the border itself?

Tags: html, css

Why does removing border thickness and color keeping border width remove the border itself?

css

```
h1
{
  color: magenta;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid #000 5px; --> border: 5px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

html

```
<body>
  <h1> This is a test </h1>
</body>
```

[image]
[image]

code:    https://jsfiddle.net/a7hoxp5f/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration...

```css
 border: solid #000 5px;
```

...is a shorthand for:

```css
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #000;
```

If you omit `solid` in the first declaration, then is equivalent to set the `border-style` to its default (initial) value. The default value of `border-style` is `none` and the standard [states for that value](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#valdef-line-style-none):

> [`none`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#valdef-line-style-none)
>
> No border. Color and width are ignored (i.e., the border has width 0).

Answer (score 2):

Because `border` is a shorthand for

```
border-width
border-style
border-color
```

So you are removing parts that are needed for it to work. Read the docs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Answer (score 1):

The default value of border-style is `None`. That's why it removes the border itself

```
removing border thickness and color
```

`solid` is not border thickness, it's `border-syle`